# Why function does nothing or returns nothing

Tags: python, function, return

I am just testing a function however the function returns nothing. I can't quite understand the rules. New to programming.

What I've tried:

```
Def func0(x, y):
    if x < y:
        z = (x*y) - x 
        return z
    else:
        w = (y*y) - 1
        return w
```

This returns nothing when called.

For example I'm expecting if I call the function:
func0(5,6)
For it to return 25

Is there a better way to achieve or write this?

Thank you

Comment: `Def` should be `def`.

Comment: When I correct that it works. `print(func0(5, 6))` prints 25.

Comment: Did you remember to print what it returns?

Comment: When I try your code (after fixing the typo - I assume this is due to phone autocorrect), the code works, and returns as you expect it to. I added some duplicate questions for the underlying background material, in case you have some wrong expectations about **what it means to return something**.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm expecting if I call the function: func0(5,6) For it to return 25

If you just *call* the function like that, then it does return the value, but you aren't *doing anything* with the returned value, so it appears like nothing was returned.

You need to call it like this which *saves* the returned value in a variable:

```
myresult = func0(5,6)
```

And then you could do something with `myresult`, like print it.